# C++ 11 binary_search and lambda function use case

Tags: c++, c++11, matrix, stl, lambda

I would like to use std::binary_search with lambda function but got compiling error.

Suppose I have a matrix, with the first column sorted.

```
1  5  9
2  4  6 
3  7  8

vector<vector<int>> matrix;
matrix.push_back(vector<int> {1, 5, 9)};
matrix.push_back(vector<int> {2, 4, 6)};
matrix.push_back(vector<int> {3, 7, 8)};
```

I want to search  whether a number exists in the first column.

(Please please don't consider the real usage of this for a moment)

And I have tried:

Version 1:

```
binary_search(begin(matrix), end(matrix), 2,
  [] (const vector<int> &r1, const vector<int> &r2) {return r1[0] < r2[0];});
```

Version 2:

```
binary_search(begin(matrix), end(matrix), vector<int> {2},
  [] (const vector<int> &r1, const vector<int> &r2) {return r1[0] < r2[0];});
```

Could any one help with me how to make it work ? (binary_search in the first column of a matrix)

**Updated:**

Thank you everyone! I learnt a lesson that I should put the original code that caused the bug here.

At last, I found out that it is because I didn't put **const** in lambda function that caused the problem. I will close this post soon. Thanks everyone again!

Comment: try `binary_search(begin(matrix), end(matrix), vector<int> {2},
  [] (const vector<int> &r1, const vector<int> &r2) {return r1[0] < r2[0];});`

Comment: Now you've fixed the original syntax error, the code [compiles for me](http://ideone.com/VnKKLw). What is the exact compile error?

Comment: The code above does not compile, as it has syntax errors unrelated to your problem.  This means you did not post code that reproduces your problem, and all I can do is guess at what your real code is.  -1.

Comment: For your last update: Try not to close your questions, unless there's a good reason to. SO is meant to help everyone, not just you. If you think as answer was helpful, simply accept it and you're done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

construct a vector with the first element as the number you want to search:

```
binary_search(begin(matrix), end(matrix), vector<int>{2},
[] (const vector<int> &r1, const vector<int> &r2) {return r1[0] < r2[0];});
```

that should work.

Update: As you have problems compiling, here is the compilable full code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  vector<vector<int>> matrix;
  matrix.push_back(vector<int> {1, 5, 9});
  matrix.push_back(vector<int> {2, 4, 6});
  matrix.push_back(vector<int> {3, 7, 8});
  binary_search(begin(matrix), end(matrix), vector<int>{2},
    [] (const vector<int> &r1, const vector<int> &r2) {return r1[0] < r2[0];});
}
```

Comment: also don't use `using namespace std;`. I left it there so it would reflect better what your code is probably like, but it's a very bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

The third argument needs to be a vector containing 2 as its first element, the syntax for which is not `2` nor `vector<int> 2` but

```
vector<int> {2}
```

Comment: Really sorry my syntax error, my second version should have { }, and it stills can not compile.

Comment: @Vindicate: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/VnKKLw) (after also fixing the mismatched brackets in the `push_back` lines). Please post the exact code (copy/pasted from what you actually compiled, not retyped), and the error message.